# cannot access ROOT account in Ubuntu 10.04 after an UPGRADE using Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: root

I just did an UPGRADE using Synaptic in my HPZ820 machine.  Before executing the UPGRADE, Synaptic gave a message that some upgrades were not authenticated and asked if I would like to continue the upgrade.  I did and the upgrade proceeded smoothly.  Upon restarting the PC, I cannot login to the Root account anymore.  If I do, Ubuntu loops back to the login page.

Could someone advise me how to undo the upgrade and return to the previous state?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to log in using your personal account?  If so, can you open the terminal and see if `sudo ls` gives you output (you may have to type your password).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, policy concerning the root account in Ubuntu is that you shouldn't use it directly, but rather `sudo` or `sudo su -` from another account.

I'd suggest you do that to reenable your root account.

Failing that, booting with a livecd or booting into rescue mode and restoring your `root` account seems to be your best course of action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what edition of Ubuntu you had before, but as far as I can remember Ubuntu has *always* had the root account disabled by default. You should never, never, *ever* run as root for everyday activities. That's just asking for trouble.

Instead, use your normal user account and simply type in your password when required for root activities.

Answer (score 0):

You run `sudo -i` from your normal user account, then with command `passwd` you can set up password for root user. If you can't do this, you may follow this instruction:

- reboot
- in grub, press e to edit boot parameters and add `init=/bin/sh` to line starting with `linux`. Press F10 to boot
- you will boot within single shell, no services will be started
- run `mount / -o remount,rw` to remount your root partition in read-write mode
- run `passwd`, change root account password
- run `sync` to flush all filesystem changes to disk
- reboot with reset button. Command `reboot` will not work, because it was not started